# Handling different datatypes for a single field in Spark read

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am reading data from json files and encountered an issue wherein for a particular field the data has different datatype.
With the command

```
   dataframe.select("standdardTime").printschema()
```

gives

```
  Data frame created from one file gives the below type
  root
  |-- standdardTime: string (nullable = true)
  
  Data frame from another file gives the below type  
  root
  |-- standdardTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Because of this data type difference I am facing issue while doing further processing as it removes the timezone components(in case of timestamp type) from the field and as I store them as string it causes a mismatch of data between both.
Is there any way to ignore the datatype of certain field/fields while loading the data to spark dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your dynamic schema for your JSON at the time of reading the JSON file from Apache spark API.

Example:

```scala
val schema = new StructType()
    .add("id", StringType, true)
    .add("Country", StringType, true)
    .add("standdardTime", TimestampType, true)

val df_with_schema = spark.read.schema(schema).json("YourJsonfile.json")
df_with_schema.printSchema()
df_with_schema.show(false)
```

Comment: this will be easy if I know the fields before hand .. most of the time the fields coming in are dynamic in nature. I don't have the field list before hand so defining a schema becomes out of question.